# Did the Gnostics have apostolic succession?

Tags: church-history, early-church, apostles, ecclesiology, gnosticism

It is often claimed that the Gnostics had apostolic succession. In particular, Clement of Alexandria is often used to show that the Gnostics claimed apostolic succession.

> Basilides, though he claims (as they boast) for his master, Glaucias,
> the interpreter of Peter. Likewise they allege that Valentinus was a
> hearer of Theudas. And he was the pupil of Paul. For Marcion, who
> arose in the same age with them, lived as an old man with the
> younger [heretics]. And after him Simon heard for a little the
> preaching of Peter. ([Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140222212816/https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Ante-Nicene_Fathers/Volume_II/CLEMENT_OF_ALEXANDRIA/The_Stromata,_or_Miscellanies/Book_VII/Chapter_XVII.#cite_note-4))

Is it true that the Gnostics had apostolic succession? And if so, what is so special about it if even the Gnostic had claim to it?

Comment: The question (as stated in the header) at the moment is ambiguous. 1. Did the Gnostics _claim_ to have apostolic succession ? 2. Did the Gnostics _actually possess, in reality_ apostolic succession. I am not certain what is being asked. Some clarity and detail is required, I suggest.

Comment: @NigelJ I'm asking whether or not they actually possessed it. It's pretty clear they made a claim to it.

Comment: My problem with this question is that it asks one thing in the title, and a different thing in the body of the question. The question in the title could be turned into a workable question here if it goes in the direction of the first suggestion by @NigelJ. But the question asked in the body is opinion-based, and would get the question closed.

Answer (score 3):

The doctrine of Apostolic Succession developed specifically to combat the Gnostic proposition that the "truth which sets one free" is not the property of the Church and its bishops, but is experienced directly by the believer. So the answer to the OP is "No." The Gnostics did appeal to certain apostles such as Thomas, Mary Magdalene, Phillip, Theudas and others. But they had no doctrine of an unbroken chain of *apostolic teaching authority* passed on from Jesus to an apostle such as Peter and thence to the bishops through the laying on of hands. Here is a summary of the [origin of the Orthodox idea](https://orthodoxwiki.org/Apostolic_succession) of Apostolic Succession:

> ...The doctrine was first formulated by St. Irenaeus of
> Lyons in the second century, in response to certain Gnostics. These
> Gnostics claimed that Christ or the Apostles passed on some teachings
> secretly, or that there were some secret apostles, and that they (the
> Gnostics) were passing on these otherwise secret teachings. Irenaeus
> responded that the identity of the original Apostles was well known,
> as was the main content of their teaching and the identity of the
> Apostles' successors. Therefore, anyone teaching something contrary to
> what was known to be apostolic teaching was not, in any sense, a
> successor to the Apostles or to Christ.

While some Gnostic churches were organized hierarchically, they tended to emphasize mystical experience of the Truth.  To quote the [Catholic Encyclopedia](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/06592a.htm):

> Gnosticism possessed no central authority for either doctrine or
> discipline; considered as a whole it had no organization similar to
> the vast organization of the Catholic Church. It was but a large
> conglomeration of sects.

**Peter Holds the Key**

The figure of Peter is particularly important in Catholic and Orthodox ecclesiology. Jesus famously gives the keys of the kingdom to Peter and declares:

> I tell you, you are Peter, and on this rock I will build my church,
> and the powers of death shall not prevail against it. (Matthew 16:18)

For traditional Christians, Peter is the rock of orthodoxy. Gnostic literature, on the other hand, often portrays Peter as not truly understanding Jesus' teaching. Instead, it depicts other disciples as receiving the secret teaching of Jesus in private. This is particularly evident in the Gospel of Thomas, as well as other Gnostic Gospels.

> And [Jesus] took him and withdrew and told him three things. When Thomas
> returned to his companions, they asked him, "What did Jesus say to
> you?" Thomas said to them, "If I tell you one of the things which he
> told me, you will pick up stones and throw them at me; a fire will
> come out of the stones and burn you up." (GT v. 13)

**What is special about the doctrine of apostolic succession in the orthodox sense is that it emphasized an unbroken tradition of teaching, centering on Peter and the original apostles, and through them to the duly ordained bishops. Gnostics sometimes appealed to apostolic authority, but they did not develop the idea that Jesus' teaching was passed on to  through ordained bishops to succeeding generations.**

Comment: If Peter was not important for the Gnostic claim to apostolic succession, why did Basilides claim that Glaucias was a student of Peter?

Comment: It may be a simple fact that Glaucias {who taught Basilides} had heard or followed Peter. If so it would only be natural for Basilides' followers to boast of this. As I mentioned, in some cases Gnostics appealed to apostolic authority and this may be an example. But that is a different thing from the doctrine of apostolic succession.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostolic_succession#Roman_Catholic_Church):

> [apostolic succession] is understood as a sign and guarantee that the Church, both local and universal, is in diachronic continuity with the apostles; a necessary but insufficient guarantor thereof.

We need to understand that apostolic succession is not a guarantee that anyone with apostolic Succession teaches the truth authoritatively, but rather that apostolic Succession has been traditionally recognized as a necessary prerequisite for such teaching. Therefore, even if the gnostics had apostolic succession (which I will dispute in a moment), this is not a guarantee that the doctrine they teach will be true.

There is not much evidence to even believe that Theudas is real. The only evidence we have is that Clement records that the Gnostics prop him up as a member of Paul's inner circle, and a receiver of "special wisdom" from Paul. However there is no evidence for this claim, and we have no writings from or referencing Theudas to evidence this besides Clement's records. Quoting again from Wikipedia:

> Theudas was allegedly the name of a Christian Gnostic thinker, who was a follower of Paul the Apostle. He went on to teach the Gnostic Valentinus. The only evidence of this connection is the testimony of Valentinius' followers and Clement of Alexandria.

It's also worth noting that Gnosticism is not a denomination, but a wide set of beliefs, many contradicting each other, that claim "special wisdom" from God. Therefore to say that Gnostics have apostolic succession is rather misleading.

Comment: I will also point out that the fact the gnostics tried to claim apostolic succession shows just how important it was to the early church!

Comment: "Therefore, even if the gnostics had apostolic succession (which I will dispute in a moment), this is not a guarantee that the doctrine they teach will be true."  Can Roman Catholic or Eastern Orthodox be substituted for gnostic in this sentence?

Comment: @MikeBorden Sure! I mean that part of Wikipedia I drew from was quoting from a Vatican document. The only difference would be that Catholics would claim ex cathedra authority for the papacy and infallible guidance from councils. Not sure on the orthodox as I’m not well acquainted with them, but I’m relatively sure they teach the same thing (that AS is necessary but not sufficient).

Comment: So AS alone doesn't guarantee anything doctrinally ... including the doctrine of AS itself, I assume ... and if the Pope, speaking ex cathedra, validates AS then everything downstream of that is validated by proxy.  But the ex cathedra claim is that speaking from the chair of Peter is passed on through AS and we've just established that AS doesn't guarantee truth.  That means the ex cathedra claim isn't **necessarily** true, it just claims that it is. The whole thing is just a loop ... Ex Cathedra is true because it is declared (through AS) to be true ex cathedra.

Comment: @MikeBorden You seem to be under the impression that AS is the reason Ex Cathedra is granted. But that's not what I would say. If we take the view that Jesus granted such authority to Peter, and then derive apostolic sucession from the actions of the people who had contact with Jesus or contact with the previously mentioned group, we can derive AS and Ex Cathedra from mere historic truth, not necessarily that they both proceed from one another.

Comment: Peter had ex cathedra...  The next guy got it through AS?

Comment: @MikeBorden Peter was given the keys of the kingdom of heaven and the power of binding and loosing, his apostolic successors were grated the same role.

Comment: Is "binding and loosing" the same as ex cathedra?

Comment: @MikeBorden I'd say so.

Comment: " "Any doctrine 'of faith or morals'*issued by the pope in his capacity as successor to St. Peter*, speaking as pastor and teacher of the Church Universal [Ecclesia Catolica], from the seat of his episcopal authority in Rome, and meant to be believed 'by the universal church,' has the special status of an ex cathedra statement."  Ex cathedra is based upon apostolic succession, which doesn't guarantee doctrinal truth.  That's what I'm getting at.

Comment: @MikeBorden I don’t think I agree but I’d rather not fill up the comment section with debate.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm still bad at that.  We can go to chat if you want, or just let it rest.

Comment: @MikeBorden I think I'd be too busy to continue this discussion unfortunately